# How to make Audacity play in loop?

Tags: audacity, looping

In Audacity, how to make a selection or a whole track play in a loop, i.e. start over at the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click the **Play** button while holding **Shift**. **Shift + Space** for short.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps maybe this will help: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_looping.html

Comment: Yes, just now I noticed it mentions the 'Loop play'. Thanks.